# How to Protect Only Certain Parts of a Web Site using the Federated Authentication Module

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-identity

I want to Integrate Windows Identity Framework(WIF) For SSO,  Federated Authentication Module of WIF is triggering on every Page of Website sends user to Signin Pgae i want on Some Page of My Website it did not apply Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the bellow to the web.config and it will allow all users to access the location.

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

In the example above I allow all users to access Default.aspx page.

Hope this helps.